# Failed to establish TCP conection over RAW SOCKET while forwarding trafic

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I'm working on Man-in-the-middle with ARP poisoning, so far I was able to reroute the traffic to my machine, and change the destination MAC to the original destination MAC, and send this modified packet to the original destination over RAW SOCKET

```c
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(0x0003));
```

but failed to establish the connection.

Comment: You can do ARP poisoning... but that doesn't change the fact that TCP does a checksum that includes the ip addresses of source and destination.  You had better to change also your ip address to make tcp to accept the SYN packet.

Comment: thanks for reply @Luis Colorado, and you are right, but what if I only change destination mac in Ethernet header and keep rest of the data from IP header to TCP exactly same, that way I don't have to worry about checksum.